# ip connect to proxy other ip 443 JUST ASKING

Tags: networking, proxy, ip, port

Is there someone who could tell me what this means.
I just set up my squid proxy but do not use them yet, i am scanning for strange behavior on my server and found this.

I know it goes to my proxy port 5128, but why whould someone in Itally connect to the States on port 443...
I don't get it, please help me out on this.

1348949815.573   1172 70.38.31.174 TCP_MISS/200 5128 CONNECT 205.188.27.208:443 - DIRECT/205.188.27.208 -

1348949819.961  21000 70.38.31.174 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT 205.188.95.208:443 - DIRECT/205.188.95.208 -

1348949824.243    920 70.38.31.174 TCP_MISS/200 5128 CONNECT 205.188.27.208:443 - DIRECT/205.188.27.208 -

1348949826.461  21000 70.38.31.174 TCP_MISS/503 0 CONNECT 205.188.95.208:443 - DIRECT/205.188.95.208 -

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely this is an malware infected PC probing for an open proxy so that it can hide behind the proxy and spam chat rooms.  The remote client had no way of knowing you just installed a web proxy, hence it was randomly probing for them.  The domain name of the IP address it was trying to connect to contains the strings "icq" and "aol".

Comment: ok thanks, i blocked the connections already.